# Can't Load the Custom Dll into new AppDomain. Show file not foud or its dependencies

Tags: appdomain

I can't load custom dll to my new `appDomain`.

```cs
AppDomainSetup appSetup = new AppDomainSetup()
{
        ApplicationName = "PluginsDomain",
        ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
        PrivateBinPath = @"Plugin",
        DisallowBindingRedirects = false,
        DisallowCodeDownload = true,
        ConfigurationFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
};

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyPlugin", null, appSetup);

byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\testUser\Documents\Visual Studio 
                   2012\Projects\BaseClass\BaseClass\bin\helpClass\HelperClass.dll");

Assembly assm= domain.Load(bytes);
Type type=assm.assm.GetExportedTypes()[0];

Object testObj=(Object)appDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(assm.FullName, type.FullName);

///Here is the problem When I try to compile it show error.
```

Comment: Why do you load the HelperClass.dll this way? Try adding it to the application base or the private bin path. If you still want to load an assembly manually, then have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx. Note that although the Load context is usually the prefered choice, the LoadFrom context is more suitable for plug-in solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement an event listener for AssemblyResolve within your remote domain ("MyPlugin") that returns the said assembly (in your case the HelperClass.dll)

Are you trying to use the HelperClass as a "Proxy"? If possible I would recommend that you create a "Proxy" (inherits from MarshalByRefObj) and then CreateInstanceAndUnwrap to your remote domain. Then implement AssemblyResolve within the "Proxy" and load the dynamic assembly via the "Proxy".

```
//Listenner to AssemblyResolve
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Name==assm.Fullname)
    {
         return assm;
    }
    else
    {
         return null;
    }
}
```

I have previously written [a post about AppDomain and implementing a "Proxy"](http://www.colormecode.com/blog/working-with-appdomain/)